# How to clear selected date time in react date time range picker?

Tags: reactjs

Once user pick some date time range how can they clear picked range

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import DatetimeRangePicker from 'react-datetime-range-picker';

class Test extends Component {

<DatetimeRangePicker
      startDate= {this.state.startDate}
      endDate={this.state.endDate}
      onStartDateBlur={this.startDateBlurHandler}
      onEndDateBlur={this.endDateBlurHandler}
      timeFormat="HH:mm"
      dateFormat="DD/MM/YY"
      inputProps={{ placeholder: ('Enter Date')}} />
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From "version": "2.0.1" the issue was fixed. using "input = {true}" property can clear using delete or backspace button.